# Node.js console.log doesn't work using August 2012 Azure SDK

Tags: node.js, azure

I am following the tutorials on the Windows Azure Node.js site:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/

however my server.js.logs file isn't being created?

In my server.js file I am issuing console.log statements but none are written to the log file.  Why is that? Whats changed in the August SDK to prevent my logs from being written?

Or what do i need to enable in order for console.log statements to be written ?

Thanks

Comment: which specific tutorial are you working on?  Is this while running local or running with Azure? With Web Sites you'll see a server.js.logs folder, with Web Roles you should see your files in the iisnode sub directory of your Web Role.

Comment: The Windows Azure Node.js August 2012 SDK changes things I think Jim.  When I inpsect the webrole folder i see an iisnode folder, inside of the issnode folder are the log files.  Not sure what microsoft are up to as they haven't given any new documenation about the sdk and what has changed etc.  So i am guessing they have done away with the server.js.logs file and gone with the issnode solution.

Comment: It's running local in azure emulator.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/168, linked to from https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/wiki/iisnode-releases (the v0.1.20 notes).

The latest Windows Azure Node.js SDK must have picked up a newer version of iisnode, and iisnode changed where it puts the log files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iisnode now puts log files in the ~/iisnode directory, and writes an index to the log files you can browse.  It also contains a new node.js script, interceptor.js which allows you to write log files to *any* location

Answer (score -1):

You must understand that console.log in node.js is used mainly for client side logging. I just tested that when you are using console.log in node.js application running on Windows Azure stdout log file could not be created so you will not get any log.

If you want to add logging to your code which is running on a web server you should be using server side logging code and I found connect library is most powerful and useful for such purpose: 
https://github.com/senchalabs/Connect

As you suggested your code is running in Compute Emulator means you are creating Windows Azure Cloud Service, you should follow your the below article step by step and you will get it working:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/

Be informed that still console.log will not show anything when your node.js code is running in Compute Emulator.

Comment: You're not quite right about console.log. In node.js that will write to stdout on the server, which is the console window when running from a command prompt.  It has nothing to do with client side logging.

Comment: You are right, what I wanted to say that on some webservers stdout could not be created that's why using it may not be good choice. When I was testing the code in Azure Cloud Service, I did not see the stdout was created however with Azure Websites other logs were posted to specific *.js.log still not specific to console.log.